# Automação de testes em páginas web

Tags: testes, testes-de-unidade, selenium-webdriver

Gostaria da indicação de ferramentas para realizar a gravação da entrada de dados na página. Já usei o **Selenium IDE**, **Selenium Web Driver**. Vi que existe o **iMacros**. Estou programando em JSF, Java e Primefaces.

Meu problema é o seguinte, eu gravei através dos Selenium IDE, mas tem hora que ele perde a referencia das entradas na página. Ai tenho que refazer o teste a partir da referencia errada, então há outra ferramentas a se trabalhar para automatizar a entrada de dados?

O iMacros não gostei muito pois ele não é tão simples e eficiente de se trabalhar como o Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 2):

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10379912/1792268) tem uma lista completa de ferramentas de automação de testes.

O Selenium é uma excelente ferramenta e recomendo tentar arrumar o problema dele seguindo alguns passos como indicado [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-stale-element-reference-exception).
Pelo que vi você tem que aguardar o elemento aparecer na pagina e ficar fixo antes de utilizar ele.

Comment: Cara a página é totalmente carregada entende, mas a referencia de alguns elementos esta errada. Não sei porque mudam. E quando se tem um `comboBox` usam o `Tab` ele n seleciona, somente através do `click`. Vou ler o que você postou. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O problema que tu estás enfrentando pode ser dividido em dois pontos:

- elementos com IDs dinâmicos
- alguns elementos parecerem como um elemento html (como uma combobox), mas na verdade são uma junção de vários elementos (ao invés de ser um  com vários  ele tem geralmente uma  com várias s ou

  s).

Nos indique como é o comportamento do código-fonte html ou mesmo da combo. Existem [tipos de localização](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements) no Selenium que podem te ajudar a interagir com elementos assim.

Answer (score 0):

Certa feita criei um framework de testes web, que na verdade é um wrapper para o Selenium, para uma empresa que trabalha com JSF.

O problema com o JSF é exatamente aquele apontado pelo Elias no primeiro item da lista: ele gera ID's dinâmicos para muitos elementos. Isso inviabiliza que a gravação pelo Selenium IDE do Firefox seja executada sempre da mesma forma.

Por exemplo, se você não definir um ID para qualquer elemento da página, o JSF vai se encarregar de fazê-lo. Um botão num formulário, por exemplo, pode acabar como o id `meuFormulario:j_id45674` (isso pode mudar de uma execução para outra) e um campo em um dataTable `tabela:0:nomeCampo` (não muda, mas é difícil de trabalhar).

Para contornar esses problemas, a solução foi usar seletores CSS e XPath usando o atributo `name` para campos de formulário e outros atributos para imagens.

Enfim, a solução que encontrei foi criar o tal framework que, entre outras coisas, provia alguns métodos que encapsulavam seletores para os componentes padrão da empresa.

Por exemplo, todo cadastro de inclusão tinha um botão com um atributo class específico, por exemplo, `botao-incluir`. Em outros casos, o botão continha uma imagem específica. Então criei uma classe que todos as classes de teste poderiam estender ou importar estaticamente e usar mais ou menos assim (em Java):

```java
public class CadastroCliente extends TestBase {

    @Test
    public void cadastrarCliente() {
        type(campo("nome"));
        type(campo("idade"));
        click(botaoIncluir());
        aguardar();
    }

}
```

Em JSF, o campo `nome`, por exemplo, poderia ter o ID gerado como `formCad:panel10:nome`. Então o método `campo()` retornaria na verdade um seletor assim:

```java
css=input[id$=':nome']
```

O seletor acima é um seletor CSS que busca um elemento `input` na página cujo ID termina com `:nome`.

Os métodos `type` e `click` que estão no código de exemplo são wrappers do selenium que fiz especialmente adaptados para o sistema em questão.

A vantagem de abstrair os métodos originais do Selenium é que frequentemente havia algum comportamento específico que exigia tratamento especial. Nesse caso, eu simplesmente ajustava a classe Wrapper sem precisar tocar nos testes.

O método `aguardar()`, por exemplo, pode automaticamente fazer verificações sobre erros de validação, isso é claro, se houver um padrão seguido em todo o sistema.